# Issue getting jQuery Data-tables to work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I was tryin to create something quick to use data tables but I am having issues with jQuery I keep getting jQuery undefined and $ undefined. I thought I had put jQuery in the correct order. I am little stumped on what to do. I know it something simple so I will continue to figure it out.

Index.php

```
<div class="container">
            <h1>Example List</h1>
            <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Equipment</th>
            <th>Qty</th>

            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php 
           <?php 
                $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;charset=utf8mb4', 'user', 'password');
                 $stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM table');
                     while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
            { ?>

            <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['date'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['equipment'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['qty'];?></td>
            </tr>

            <?php } ?>

            </tbody>

            </table>
     </div>

            <?php //script section ?>

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">           
            <scriptsrc="jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                 $('.table').DataTable();
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going for the low hanging apple here, but is `<script src="jquery.js"></script>` present as-is in your index? Seems to be a typing error.

Comment: omg How embarrassing thanks that's all it was. Well teaches me to double check my typing errors.

Comment: Well I updated the code and kept the error so others who come across this issue can see and they would also get the proper code for it.